# Explicitly make a target with a variable name

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a `Makefile` with the following format:

```
.PHONY: all

target1 := file1
target2 := $(target1).txt

all: $(target2)

$(target1): prerequisite1
    recipe

$(target2): $(target1)
    recipe
```

`target2` depends on `target1`, and `make` will correctly substitute the strings to create the file names. However, on my system, the file names and paths are quite tedious to type out; I'm wondering if there is any 
way to specifically make `target1` while referring to its name *not as the file path, but as the variable*.

For example, I would like to be able to invoke:

```
$ make $(target1)
```

rather than

```
$ make path/to/file1
```

I want to do this because I change the variables quite a bit and the structure of my `Makefile` has many intermediates that are occasionally difficult to trace back to their literal file paths, but are easy to `make` based on the variable names that I have assigned them.

The above does not work, and I have read the `man` page as well as done quite a bit of searching here and on Google. Just wondering if anyone has come across this problem before and found a solution.

Comment: A target that looks something like `variable-% : $($*);` and called via `make variable-target1`, maybe?

Comment: @user2722968 Thanks. :) Sorry, I may be getting caught up in the syntax, but `make target1` returns that make cannot find the target.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bit clunky to due use of recursion, but it does what you want:

```
target1 := file1

$(target1):
    @echo "Hello from $@"

variable-%:
    $(MAKE) $($*)
```

gives

```
$ make variable-target1
make file1
Hello from file1
```

Comment: Wow, I'm sorry that I did not understand from your comment, but this is absolutely perfect and exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much!

Comment: While this works, `make` would get confused if there was an *actual* file by the name `variable-target1`. Therefore I wouldn't recommend this "tricky" solution.

Answer (score 3):

That's what *phony* targets are for. A *phony* target is a target that *isn't* the name of an output file. Often, the default target (that's whatever target appears first in the Makefile) is *phony* and by convention called `all`. So just modify your Makefile to something like this:

```
.PHONY: all target1 target2

target1 := file1
target2 := $(target1).txt

# phony rules with dependencies
all: target2

target2: $(target2) target1

target1: $(target1)

# file rules with prerequisites
$(target1): prerequisite1
    recipe

$(target2):
    recipe
```

As a "best practice", list the dependencies that aren't directly used for creating the real targets in the prerequisite list of the *phony* targets and the dependencies that are indeed input files in the prerequisite list of the actual file targets.

---

Note this will work without declaring the targets in `.PHONY` **as long as** there's not by accident a file with the name of the *phony* target. Such a file would confuse `make`, therefore always list all your *phony* targets in `.PHONY`, so `make` knows they don't produce a file of their name.